# U-Boot i2c detects my device (70) but Linux i2c does not. Why?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c

I am in the process of migrating from Linux 3.10 to a slightly newer version, Linux 4.4.8. After the migration it seems that i2c can no longer see some of my hardware. The hardware itself has not changed whatsoever and works fine in the previous linux version (3.10).

The problem I am running into now is that my i2c commands are no longer working.

When trying to write to the device I get a failed write.

```
[]# i2cset -y 0 0x70 0 1 b
Error: Write failed
```

Then I decided to run the i2cdetect to determine what can be seen and this is the output i get

In Linux:

```
[]# i2cdetect -y -a 0
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: 20 21 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- 64 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

In U-Boot:

```
[u-boot]# i2c probe
Valid chip addresses: 20 21 64 70
```

**What would be the reason that I can see my device in U-Boot but I can't see my device in Linux?**

I suspect the device tree might need to be modified? But I checked the old dtsi files and nothing is different between the i2c0's in the two Linux versions...

i2cdump gives all X's for output

```
[]# i2cdump -y 0 0x70
No size specified (using byte-data access)
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
00: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
10: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX...
```

> i2c host controller: linux-4-4-8/drivers/i2c/busses/**i2c-mv64xxx.c**

Devices

0x20, 0x21: PCA9555 IO Port Expanders

0x70: PCA9548A i2c Multiplexer

Comment: Have you tried i2cdump? I saw some cases when i2cdetect have not recognized device, while i2cdump have worked. Many things depend on i2c device. What is your i2c host controller? is this device have some external power interfaces? What kind of device is it?

Comment: I have made edits to my question that hopefully answer your questions @AlexHoppus Also as a side note, the hardware on my board has not changed whatsoever. The only thing that has is the kernel. If I build the older kernel everything works fine.

Comment: The device you have mentioned might have gpio reset see i2c-mux-pca954x.c probe. Have you checked that it works properly?

Comment: I was able to figure it out, thank you @AlexHoppus for leading me to the correct path for solving this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newer kernel has a different parent dtsi file that defines various mpp's for pinctrl

The dts file I was using contained some Ethernet devices that were defined but were never used by us, we piggy backed off another team's device tree since our hardware was ALMOST identical. Those ethernet's used the following mdio

```
mdio@72004 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&mdio_pins>; //<==== This was the problem

    phy0: ethernet-phy@0 {
        reg = <0>;
    };
};
```

The mdio uses &mdio_pins and, **in the newer kernel**, is defined as

```
mdio_pins: mdio-pins {
    marvell,pins = "mpp4", "mpp5";
    marvell,function = "ge";
};
```

It just so happens to be that the **gpio reset** for my device is **mpp5**.

I changed the ethernet section of the device tree to the following

```
ethernet@70000 {
    status = "disabled";
};

mdio@72004 {
    status = "disabled";
};

ethernet@30000 {
    status = "disabled";
};
```

This solved the problem of the device not showing up in i2cdetect and the hardware is working as before.

*It was my own fault for assuming the device tree I inherited was concrete in definition of the hardware being used.*